Output Current of Darlington Amplifier
I'm working with Darlington amplifier and when I try to simulate the circuit using LTSPice. The result is as below. When I remove the resistor at Emitter of Q2, the current is constant, but if I add a resistor, it become linear and go up. As far as I know, without input signal, the output current at Emitter of Q2 must stay the same, but this result make me confused. What happened?


You did not use a source voltage generator on the base with a capacitor interfacing ...

It's a numerical error due to the floating point data compression that LTspice uses, by default. If you add the following spice line to your schematic:
.options plotwinsize=0

Then it will fix the issue.
Here's what you got without it:

Here's what you will get with it:

Sloped line before, straight line after.
It's just a minor numerical issue. Don't worry about it too much.
